# How can I pass an object `Message` to the route?

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl, spring-integration-amqp

I create a flow, which consumes messages from RabbitMQ and after that distributes to the appropriate services by type using the router.
Methods in services take argument `Message<?>`, because I need to use headers there. But in this method I receive only message payload with type `java.lang.String` instead `org.springframework.messaging.Message` and 
I get error `java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to org.springframework.messaging.Message`.

Payload isn't suitable for me, because I need to get headers from message.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow testFlow(String queueName,
                                ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                Service1 service1,
                                Service2 service2) {
    SimpleMessageListenerContainer consumerListener = new SimpleMessageListenerContainer(connectionFactory);
    consumerListener.addQueueNames(queueName);
    return IntegrationFlows.from(Amqp.inboundAdapter(consumerListener))
            .transform(s -> s, ConsumerEndpointSpec::transactional)
            .<Message<?>, String>route(HeadersUtil::getType, m -> m
                    .subFlowMapping(Type.SERVICE_1, sf -> sf.handle(service1::handleProcedure))
                    .subFlowMapping(Type.SERVICE_2, sf -> sf.handle(service2::handleProcedure)))
            .get();
}
```

The signature of the method `handleProcedure` is as follows:

`void handleProcedure(Message<?> message)`

I expect to get headers of `Message` in the method `handleProcedure`, but I get exception now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you didn't understand the stack trace properly.

Your `void handleProcedure(Message<?> message)` and its `service1::handleProcedure` method reference fully fits to the `public B handle(MessageHandler messageHandler) {` method signature in the `IntegrationFlowDefinition`.

Your problem is here:

```
.<Message<?>, String>route(HeadersUtil::getType,
```

Your `HeadersUtil::getType` expects a message, but the type for the lambda invocation is a `payload` which is `String` in your case.

This should work:

```
.<Message<?>, String>route(Message.class, HeadersUtil::getType,
```

Answer (score 0):

The `handle(GenericHandler<P>)` version of `.handle`, which you are using, only gets the payload.

If you want to receive the complete message, you need to use a different overloaded `.handle`, such as `handle("service1", "handleProcedure")` or `.handle(service1, "handleProcedure")`.